# Promise.all processes the promises in a group of 6 at each time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-http

I wanna make a bunch of (let's say 20) HTTP POST requests (in order to send information of an app to some HTTP servers) simultaneously.

I am using *http* angular service to return a promise:

```
function deployPromise(server, app){
  return $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: server.url,
    data: app
  });
}
```

For simultaneous deployments I am using Promise.all that gets the array of deployPromises:

```
function deploy(servers, app){
  Promise.all(servers.map(function(server){
    return deployPromise(server, app);
  }));
}
```

Finally I call *deploy* function with array of available servers and the app info:

```
deploy(servers, app);
```

To my surprise, instead of executing all at once, requests are sent (in otherwords, *deployPromises* are resolved) in a group of 6. I mean, when the first 6 calls are done, then the second 6 calls will be processed and so on.

Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: Same if you use `$q.all` instead?

Comment: If browsers didn't limit connections per host, all hell would break loose.

Comment: Sure but still I would too expect promises in parallel completing at the same time, despite being invoked in bulks.

Comment: @cYrixmorten - how could they complete at the same time if the browser limits the number of simultaneous connections?

Comment: @JaromandaX Not complete at the same time, but deferred until all are completed before by Promise.all

Comment: Yes. Theres no indication in the question that this isn't happening

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a browser limitation, you can't open a infinite number of simultaneous connections.
[Max parallel http connections in a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser/#30064610)